# Como usar SetStyleSheet Background Image

Tags: python, pyqt5

Hice una nueva ventana con PyQt5, cuando quiero poner una imagen de fondo, he usado self.setStyleSheet ("QMainWindow {background-image: url (FON.jpg)}") pero no sucede nada en la ventana que todavía está gris, Alguien me puede ayudar, soy nuevo con PyQt5.

Este es el Codigo:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QRegion, QPixmap, QPalette, QColor, QFont, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QDir, QFile, QFileInfo, QPropertyAnimation, QRect, QAbstractAnimation, 
QTranslator, QLocale, QLibraryInfo, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget, QDialog, QPushButton, QMainWindow, 
QMessageBox,QFrame, QFileDialog, QLabel, QStyleFactory, QStatusBar



class VentanaMenu(QDialog):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(VentanaMenu, self).__init__()
    
    self.setWindowTitle("Menu - INICM")
    self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icono.png"))
    self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
    self.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{background-image: url(FON.jpg)}")
    self.setFixedSize(500, 600)

    
    

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
aplicacion = QApplication(sys.argv)

ventana = VentanaMenu()
ventana.show()

sys.exit(aplicacion.exec_())
```

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta a español

Comment: Estás en SO en español.

Comment: Hice una nueva ventana con PyQt5, cuando quiero poner una imagen de fondo, he usado self.setStyleSheet ("QMainWindow {background-image: url (FON.jpg)}") pero no sucede nada en la ventana que todavía está gris, Alguien me puede ayudar, soy nuevo con PyQt5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código dice QMainWindow:

```
"QMainWindow{background-image: url(FON.jpg)}"
```

Pero tu ventana es QDialog:

```
class VentanaMenu(QDialog):
```

Estás intentando modificar el elemento incorrecto mediante QSS. Así que la solución sería:

```
"QDialog {background-image: url(FON.jpg)}"
```

Leete esto, te ayudará: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

Comment: Ohhhh sii, vale muchas Gracias